# could not find TemporaryGeneratedFile_GUID

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I copied and pasted a visual studio solution from a folder to another, and now when I open the new one I see in the output window (show output is set to intelliSense):

```
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\File\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs'.
```

How can I make this messages go away?

Comment: You could try editing the solution file in notepad and looking to see if there are any reference to the old path, updating as needed.

Comment: I seem to remember that I did that, but I couldn't find any ref to those files

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure I had tried, but right now I don't have any test cases

Answer (score 6):

open your projectname.csproj file in any text editor such as notepad++. Find code similar as follow:

```
<Compile Include="obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs" />
<Compile Include="obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs" />
<Compile Include="obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs" />
<Compile Include="obj\Release\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs" />
<Compile Include="obj\Release\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs" />
<Compile Include="obj\Release\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs" />
```

Remove those lines and restart visual studio or unload your solution and reload the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting the suo file. That seems to help my case sometimes.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the solution that caused this issue anymore. I'll try to find some similar issues among my files

Comment: I have tried to delete the bin and obj folder but this could not help. When I deleted the suo files it worked again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this github issue may be the answer: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7110

with the resolution description

> "Yup. roslyn is trying to read the files when this happens, and
>   clearly the files are no longer available or are locked. We're
>   printing something into the output window so people know this so
>   they're not confused as to why things like intellisense aren't showing
>   full information about their project."

Answer (score 0):

### Answer for VS2017

1. Make sure your `IntermediateOutputPath` and `OutputPath` destination paths doesn't have spaces at the end.
2. Close the project and selete these these three folders, then reopen

   - IntermediateOutputPath
   - OutputPath
   - .vs (This is a hidden directory in the project directory)

Answer (score 0):

Do full Rebuild under the relevant configuration and when it succeeds, close and re-open VS and those spurious messages should disappear.

I had this yesterday and tried every suggestion under the sun and none of them worked.
I had another one this morning and the full Rebuild sorted it.

Edit: I just noticed, the projects where this was happening are not selected for Build in Configuration Manager. I had to do a /bin and /obj folder delete a few days before to cure another issue, so this might have been caused by remnants of those old builds not being refreshed by my regular build process.